# Altitudes of a rhombus form a rectangle

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, euclidean-geometry

From Kiselev / Givental:

> From the intersection point of the diagonals of a rhombus perpendiculars are dropped to the sides of the rhombus.  Prove that the feet of these perpendiculars are vertices of a rectangle.

My solution is below, to which I request verification, improvements, or feedback.  The proof is surprisingly (at least to me) simple.

---

Let $PQRS$ be a rhombus with center $O$.  From $O$, drop perpendiculars to $A,B,C,D$ respectively.

Since $PQRS$ is a rhombus, then $\triangle OPQ, \triangle OQR, \triangle ORS, \triangle OSP$ are congruent right triangles, whose altitudes are congruent.  But $OA,OB,OC,OD$ are simply the altitudes of those triangles and therefore congruent. **[1]** Thus, $AC$ and $BD$ are congruent and mutually bisecting and therefore the diagonals of rectangle $ ABCD$.

**Update [1]** (As suggested by Calvin Lin): Furthermore, note that $OA$ and $OC$ are colinear, since they share point $O$ and are perpendicular to parallel lines $PQ$ and $RS$.  Likewise, $OB$ and $OD$ are colinear.

Comment: You should prove AOC, BOD are straight lines, or at least state that.  (Otherwise, why is AC, BD congruent and mutually bisecting). $\quad$ Yes I know it seems obvious to you, but for such "surprisingly simple" proofs, it's best to nail down all of the details.

Comment: @CalvinLin Great point.  Please take a look at updated.